# MailCore 2 - send email Excenge Server

Tags: ios, xcode, smtp, mailcore2

I'm trying to send an email from my app with Exchange server. But i keep getting "Unable to authenticate with the current session's credentials." I commented out everything i tried, as hostname, or port, or connection type.

What can i do ?

```
  MCOSMTPSession *smtpSession = [[MCOSMTPSession alloc] init];
smtpSession.hostname = @"smpt.office365.com";
//smtpSession.hostname = @"smpt.outlook.office365.com";
//smtpSession.port = 587;
smtpSession.port = 25;
smtpSession.username = @"";
smtpSession.password = @"";
smtpSession.authType = MCOAuthTypeSASLPlain;
//smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionTypeTLS;
smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionTypeStartTLS;

MCOMessageBuilder *builder = [[MCOMessageBuilder alloc] init];
MCOAddress *from = [MCOAddress addressWithDisplayName:@""
                                              mailbox:@""];
MCOAddress *to = [MCOAddress addressWithDisplayName:nil
                                            mailbox:@""];
[[builder header] setFrom:from];
[[builder header] setTo:@[to]];
[[builder header] setSubject:@"My message"];
[builder setHTMLBody:@"This is a test message!"];
NSData * rfc822Data = [builder data];

MCOSMTPSendOperation *sendOperation =
[smtpSession sendOperationWithData:rfc822Data];
[sendOperation start:^(NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error sending email: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Successfully sent email!");
    }
}];
```

Comment: "Unable to authenticate" means your login and password are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`smtpSession.hostname = @"smpt.office365.com";
                         ^^^^`

Typo? Should it be `smtp`?